# Disable automatic package update in RPM package manager for single application in CentOS7

Tags: centos, package-management, rpm

How can I disable automatic package update in RPM package manager for a single application in CentOS 7?

Answer (score 5):

To disable single application from being updated automatically, while leaving other rpms enabled for automatic updates, add that rpm name to ignore list in `/etc/yum.conf`.

You need to add the line `exclude=` and name of the rpm to ignore for updates.

For instance if you don't want Apache(httpd) package to get updated you would add `httpd*` to that line:

```
exclude=httpd*
```

If you are running `yum update` manually you need to use `--exclude` option:

```
yum update --exclude=httpd*
```

Comment: Sorry. Question updated.

Comment: I did this change in yum.conf. but isn't it for yum package manager? Is this same config file also used for RPM?

Comment: yes, yum is used for rpm management, rpm command doesn't install dependencies for rpm, yum takes care to install all dependencies when rpm is being installed or updated.